# IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries idb2Command crash when insert parameter with empty string

Tags: c#, db2, db2-400, iseries-navigator

```
var ibmConnnectionString = "DataSource=10.12.61.12;Naming=SQL;LibraryList=LINSYS;UserID=*****;Password=*****;";

using (iDB2Connection db2Conn = new iDB2Connection(ibmConnnectionString))
            {
                db2Conn.Open();
                //  using (iDB2Transaction trans = db2Conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (iDB2Command cmd = db2Conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        // cmd.Transaction = trans;
                        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO LINSYS.ALENBN (
                                    POLNUM, FEDRNUM, BENFCD, BNSURN, BNNAME, BNFANM, CSBRDT, BNPART, CSADT)
                                    VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8)";

                        cmd.DeriveParameters();

                        cmd.Parameters["@p0"].Value = 148690; //iDB2Numeric
                        cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = 11001; //iDB2Numeric
                        cmd.Parameters["@p2"].Value = 99;    //iDB2Numeric                     
                        cmd.Parameters["@p3"].Value = String.Empty; //iDB2Char Not NULL Default ('')
                        cmd.Parameters["@p4"].Value = String.Empty; //iDB2Char Not NULL Default ('')
                        cmd.Parameters["@p5"].Value = String.Empty; //iDB2Char Not NULL Default ('')
                        cmd.Parameters["@p6"].Value = 0; //iDB2Numeric

                        cmd.Parameters["@p7"].iDB2Value = 100M;//iDB2Numeric
                        cmd.Parameters["@p8"].iDB2Value = String.Empty; //iDB2Char Not NULL Default ('')

                        try
                        {

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch(iDB2SQLErrorException ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex);
                        }


                    }
                }
```

When executing the command ExecuteNonQuery, console app stops with no error
If I omit the iDb2Char Parameters or these parameters contains any single characters (even space) then the command working successfully. The problem is when I pass String.Empty 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are getting a non `iDB2SQLErrorException`.

Try this:

```
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(iDB2SQLErrorException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     Console.Writeline(ex);
}
```

Then if there are ANY exceptions, you will know what the problem was.  It could be something like the field doesn't allow 0 length strings and for some reason it throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: No there is not just the IDE of visual studio stops

Comment: You mean that `ExecuteNonQuery` never returns?

Comment: If I am in debug mode the ExecuteNonQuery stops Visual Studio debug mode and if I run this from the console executable application nothing happens

Comment: If you set `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` to a short value, say 5 (seconds), do you get a timeout exception?

Comment: Nothing happens its stops immediately

Comment: The problem has to do with empty string. If a put either one character it's working

Comment: Those types are defined like  datatype = character, code  = use CCSID with default value '' and not null

Comment: Also, I tried to use ado.net odbc library and with ODBC is working

Comment: It is so weird. I used IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries for better performance but as I see I will go back with ODBC